# Postgresql: how can install it in a different location in a linux server?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I would like to install `postgresql` in a linux (ubuntu) server.

If I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

it is going to install it in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
```

while I would like to have it in

```
/home/database/postgresql/9.5/main
```

Answer (score 3):

Postgres uses the `PGDATA` environment variable to understand where do you want it to work. Edit the init script (either `/etc/init.d/postgresql` or `/usr/lib/systemd/postgresql.service`) and set the `PGDATA` accordingly. For example:

```
# Note: changing PGDATA will typically require adjusting SELinux
# configuration as well.

# Note: do not use a PGDATA pathname containing spaces, or you will
# break postgresql-setup.
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Note: avoid inserting whitespace in these Environment= lines, or you may
# break postgresql-setup.

# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/var/sql/pgsql/

# Where to send early-startup messages from the server (before the logging
# options of postgresql.conf take effect)
# This is normally controlled by the global default set by systemd
# StandardOutput=syslog

# Disable OOM kill on the postmaster
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

#ExecStartPre=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300
ExecStop=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast
ExecReload=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA} -s

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may also try to symlink `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` to `/home/database/postgresql/9.5/main` - might be simpler.